# Аналог tooltip'a

Tags: c#, winforms

Как я понимаю, tooltip работает только при наведении курсора на объект, рядом с которым данный tooltip появляется. А можно ли сделать так, чтобы он срабатывал не от наведения, а просто от какого-то события? Например:

```
if (a==2) 
{
    System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip ToolTip2 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip();
    ToolTip2.SetToolTip(this.pictureBox9, "Что-то");
}
```

Или подскажите аналог такого всплывающего окошка (не messagebox, чтобы просто всплывал и не отвлекал пользователя). Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У ToolTip есть ряд перегрузок метода `Show()`. Попробуйте их.